# Digikam: How to use EXIF info (e.g. Manufacturer = Nikon) as filter criteron in Digikam?

Tags: digikam

Digikam: How to use EXIF info (e.g. Manufacturer = Nikon) as filter criteron in Digikam?

*(If I type "Nikon" in the ["Text Filter" in the sidebar](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-graphics/digikam/using-sidebar.html#using-sidebar-filters) nothing shows.)*

Comment: Have you tagged each image taken using a Nikon camera with a 'Nikon' text tag?

Comment: Nope; that would be something I'd only do to "port" the functionality from the "Advanced Search" to the sidebar - as a slightly annoying workaround...

Answer (score 4):

["Advanced Search"](https://www.pks.mpg.de/%7Emueller/docs/suse10.2/html/opensuse-manual_en/manual/sec.digikam.search.html) (as opposed to the sidebar) seems to have that functionality.